# Results query inner join (jdbc) in table (view) Spring MVC

Tags: spring, join, view

Could someone help me as I show the result of an inner join query in a view in Spring.

How do I return all fields from all inner join tables and show in view?

Ex from Model Class:

```
@NotEmpty(message="Destino não pode estar vazio")
private Integer idDestinoAgendamento;
private Integer idMotoristaAgendamento;
private Integer idAutomovelAgendamento;
private Integer idRotaAgendamento;

@NotEmpty(message="Data não pode estar vazia")
private String dataSolicitacaoPacApp;

@NotEmpty(message="Hora não pode estar vazia")
private String horaSolicitacaoPacApp;

@NotEmpty(message="Status não pode estar vazio")
private String statusAgendamento;
private Destino destino;
private Motorista motorista;
private Automovel automovel;
```

Ex do DAO:

```
public List buscarTodosAgendamentos()
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM bAgendamento AS agendamento INNER JOIN bsDestino AS destino"
     + " ON agendamento.idDestinoAgendamento = destino.idDestino INNER JOIN"
     + " bsMotorista AS motorista ON agendamento.idMotoristaAgendamento = motorista.idMotorista "
     + " INNER JOIN bsAutomovel AS automovel ON agendamento.idAutomovelAgendamento = "
     + " automovel.idAutomovel INNER JOIN bsRota AS rota ON agendamento.idRotaAgendamento ="
     + " rota.idRota ORDER BY agendamento.dataSolicitacaoPacAPP ASC "   
    List list = 

      namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql,getSqlParameterByModel(null), new AgendamentoMapper());

    return list;
}
```

View (return fields object Destino, Automovel...):

```
 c:forEach items="${listAgendamento}" var="agendamento"

 ${agendamento.idAgendamento}
 ${agendamento.cpfPacienteSolicitacaoPacApp}
 ${agendamento.idDestinoAgendamento}
 ${agendamento.idMotoristaAgendamento}
 ${agendamento.idAutomovelAgendamento}
 ${agendamento.idRotaAgendamento}
 ${agendamento.dataSolicitacaoPacApp}
 ${agendamento.horaSolicitacaoPacApp}
 ${agendamento.statusAgendamento}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SiteJoinCategory {
private Category category;
private Site site;
public Category getCategory() {
return category;
}
public void setCategory(Category category) {
this.category = category;
}
public Site getSite() {
return site;
}
public void setSite(Site site) {
this.site = site;
}

}
public class Site {
private Integer siteId;
private String siteName;
private Integer categoryId;

public Integer getSiteId() {
return siteId;
}
public void setSiteId(Integer siteId) {
this.siteId = siteId;
}
public String getSiteName() {
return siteName;
}
public void setSiteName(String siteName) {
this.siteName = siteName;
}
public Integer getCategoryId() {
return categoryId;
}
public void setCategoryId(Integer categoryId) {
this.categoryId = categoryId;
}
}
public class Category {
private Integer categoryId;
private String categoryName;

public Integer getCategoryId() {
return categoryId;
}
public void setCategoryId(Integer categoryId) {
this.categoryId = categoryId;
}
public String getCategoryName() {
return categoryName;
}
public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
this.categoryName = categoryName;
}
}
@Component
public class SiteJoinCategoryDao {

@Resource
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List findAll() {
String sql = "select site., cat. " +
"from t_site site inner join m_category cat " +
"ON site.category_id = cat.category_id";
RowMapper rowMapper = new SiteCategoryRowMapper();

List list = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper);
return list;
}

/**
* RowMapper
*/
protected class SiteCategoryRowMapper implements RowMapper {

@Override
public SiteJoinCategory mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
SiteJoinCategory siteJoinCategory = new SiteJoinCategory();
Site site = new Site();
Category category = new Category();

site.setSiteId(rs.getInt("site.site_id"));
site.setSiteName(rs.getString("site.site_name"));
site.setCategoryId(rs.getInt("site.category_id"));

category.setCategoryId(rs.getInt("cat.category_id"));
category.setCategoryName(rs.getString("cat.category_name"));

siteJoinCategory.setSite(site);
siteJoinCategory.setCategory(category);
return siteJoinCategory;
}
}
}
View (exemplo:

${siteJoinCategory.site.siteName}
${siteJoinCategory.category.categoryName}
```